# Get rows where all values are nan in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to filter for names where all the values in column a are nan

this is what I have tried

```
full.groupby('name')['opp'].isna().any(1)
```

however this returns the error message:

```
AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'isna' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method
```

here is a sample of my data

```
name            opp 
 f              nan
 f              nan
 g               f
 g              nan
 g              nan
 g              nan
 k              nan
```

desired output is

```
name     opp
f        nan
f        nan
k        nan
```

Comment: @jezrael not necessarily

Comment: OK, then use any of 4 solutions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`GroupBy.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.all.html) for test if all `True` (all `NaN`s values) per groups and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = full[full['opp'].isna().groupby(full['name']).transform('all')]
```

Alternative is get all `name`s which contains at least one non missing value and filter original name column by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df = full[~full['name'].isin(full.loc[full['opp'].notna(), 'name'])]
```

---

```
print (df)
  name  opp
0    f  NaN
1    f  NaN
6    k  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [filter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html):

```
print(df.groupby('name').filter(lambda x: x['opp'].isna().all()))
```

**Output**

```
  name  opp
0    f  NaN
1    f  NaN
6    k  NaN
```

As an alternative you could use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) + [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin):

```
lookup = set(df.dropna(subset=['opp']).name.values)
print(df[~df.name.isin(lookup)])
```

**Output**

```
  name  opp
0    f  NaN
1    f  NaN
6    k  NaN
```

Comment: For small dataset, this works perfectly fine. Groupby filter tends to struggle with big dataset

Comment: @jezrael yep. Groupby filtering is one of the cases where you need to balance the simplicity of code and performance.